# How do you hide keycloak.json in URL

Tags: angular, security, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm currently setting up an angular4 project with keycloak integration. And so as I follow the examples from keycloak github repository (angular2-product-example), I created a keycloak.json client configuration file and uploaded it on my web project, which is accessible via web url. I need it there so that I can initialized the js adapter:

```
let keycloakAuth: any = new Keycloak('keycloak.json');
```

But I have a concern with regards to security, the configuration with keycloak's client secret is accessible from the url. How is it normally secured in this case?

Comment: "as I follow the tutorial" — What tutorial? The extra context might help people provide a good answer.

Comment: Keycloak examples from keycloak github repository https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/demo-template

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, this is not possible, as blocking it from being read by the user would mean blocking it from being read by Keycloak-js (they use XMLHttpRequest, but before the authorization, so requiring authorization to access keycloak.json in the first place is impossible).

As outlined in [this tutorial](https://blog.scalac.io/user-authentication-with-keycloak-part1.html) (for React, mind you), you have to have a public client set up for your frontend, as the frontend will be exposed in vanilla code. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109944/keycloak-javascript-adapter-receives-400-bad-request-in-internet-explorer/52114189#52114189), a private client *might* work on Firefox or Chrome, but it inevitably produces a 400 through Internet Explorer, and is not guaranteed to work in either way..

P.S., since, I assume, you are using the standard Keycloak-js adapter, you can also use simply `const keycloak : Keycloak.KeycloakInstance = Keycloak();`, and it should automatically take the `keycloak.json` file that is located in the same folder. This will mean less exposure to the file name to people unfamiliar with Keycloak-js.

Answer (score -1):

You should use your `.htaccess` file to prevent access to specific files or folders on your web hosting. More info about the matter can be found on the 
link below:

[How to prevent access with htaccess](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/htaccess-prevent-access)

Comment: Then the client-side JavaScript which needs to read it won't be able to access it either. You could get the same effect, with less effort, by just deleting the file.

Comment: Blocking access to file via `.htaccess` won't block it for scripts running on the same domain. If configured properly of course.

Comment: It won't block access for *server-side* scripts (but dealing with those is best done by moving the file outside the document root entirely) but the question is talking about Angular. It's about client-side scripts.